# CDK - How to get object reference to resource that is added to CFN template in the background by method

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-service-catalog, aws-cdk

Once I mitigate `ResourceNotFoundException` when trying to add `ServiceCatalog` `LaunchRoleConstraint` to the Portfolio.

It turned out, that in the background, CDK is creating [PortfolioProductAssociation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-servicecatalog-portfolioproductassociation.html) when [portfolio_obj.add_product(product_obj)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_servicecatalog/Portfolio.html#aws_cdk.aws_servicecatalog.Portfolio.add_product) method is used.

It work fine until you want to add an existing role - then you need to use [CfnLaunchRoleConstraint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_servicecatalog/CfnLaunchRoleConstraint.html) instead of using e.g. [portfolio_obj.set_local_launch_role_name()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_servicecatalog/Portfolio.html#aws_cdk.aws_servicecatalog.Portfolio.set_local_launch_role_name).
`set_local_launch_role_name()` method by default adds proper depends on to `association` object - pure `CfnLaunchRoleConstraint` object is not.

So, here we can mitigate `ResourceNotFoundException` because setting-up launch constraints requires already done association of the product to the portfolio - appropriate `depends on` reference is required.

To fix it I just use [CfnPortfolioProductAssociation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_servicecatalog/CfnPortfolioProductAssociation.html) instead `add_product` method, so I was able to create `depends on` with association...

---

My question is: is it possible to somehow retrieve such objects, like this association object (generated by `add_product()` method), into my stack class, to be able to refer to them?

I know that is not a necessary functionality, due to each `Cfn*` resource - I'm just curious...

(I'm using Python CDK-v2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can retrieve the underlying Cfn* objects that are created by L2 objects, either in the constructor, or through helper functions like `add_product()` by using escape hatches:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_resource

The trick about this is getting the Id of the resource you want. Sometimes you can just use `node.default_child` but if it's not the default child of the L2/L3 construct then you may need `node.find_child`. But that can be tough because in this case the Id is not a static value and would be hard to guess:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/74318c7d22bfc00de9e005f68a0a6aaa58c7db39/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-servicecatalog/lib/private/association-manager.ts#L24

So instead you can look at just iterating over all children until you find the CfnPortfolioProductAssociation class. I'm not a python guy so I'm going to psuedo code it here:

```
for resource in thing.node.children:
    if isinstance(resource, CfnPortfolioProductAssociation):
        # start modifying resource here as needed
```

Note: if I got the python code here wrong PLEASE edit this response to fix it.